How to get cors headers working in Laravel 9
For some reason, cors headers are not showing up in my Laravel 9 application. I've set the URLs in config/cors.php, allowed_origin, but i still get "(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403." and i don't see the correct header when i look at the request headers in the web console. is there something i need to do turn cors on?
in config/cors.php, i have the following (i know i only need one of the domains but i was going to figure out which domain once it worked at all.)
'allowed_origins' => ['https://checkout.stripe.com', 'https://dev2.example.com'],


Share the all other settings of cors.php and route-defination through which you are accessing the paths.
